# Cucumber/Capybara not finding simple_form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara, bdd

When I view source the id of the text field matches what I am calling for in the test.

Here is the form field:
`<fieldset class="fsStyle">

        <legend class="legendStyle">*** Summarize Your Edits for History/Timeline ***</legend>
        <%= f.input :latest_update, input_html: { id: 'blurb' } %>
        <%= f.input :send_update %>
    </fieldset>`

here is the cuke feature:

```

```
Feature: Edit article with blurbs
  In order to send a clear update
  As an editor
  I want to add a summary of my edits

Scenario: Article Edit With Blurb
  Given I am on the show page
  And I follow "Edit"
  When I fill in "blurb" with "This is my edit summary"
  And I press "Update Article"
  And visit the history page
  Then I should see "This is my edit summary"
```

```

the step definition:

`Given(/^I follow "(.*?)"$/) do |link_name|
  click_link link_name
end`

the view source:
```

```
<fieldset class="fsStyle">              
        <legend class="legendStyle">*** Summarize Your Edits for History/Timeline ***</legend>
        <div class="form-group text optional article_latest_update"><label class="text optional control-label" for="blurb">Latest update</label><textarea id="blurb" class="text optional form-control" name="article[latest_update]">
a test update to check boolean</textarea></div>
        <div class="form-group boolean optional article_send_update"><div class="checkbox"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="article[send_update]" /><label class="boolean optional" for="article_send_update"><input class="boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="article[send_update]" id="article_send_update" />Send update</label></div></div>
    </fieldset>
```

```

Here is the test output including the error:
```

```
Using the default profile...
Feature: Edit article with blurbs
  In order to send a clear update
  As an editor
  I want to add a summary of my edits

  Scenario: Article Edit With Blurb                       # features/edit_with_blurbs.feature:6
    Given I am on the show page                           # features/step_definitions/path_steps.rb:4
    And I follow "Edit"                                   # features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:4
    When I fill in "blurb" with "This is my edit summary" # features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:8
      Unable to find field "blurb" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:9:in `/^I fill in "(.*?)" with "(.*?)"$/'
      features/edit_with_blurbs.feature:9:in `When I fill in "blurb" with "This is my edit summary"'
    And I press "Update Article"                          # features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:12
    And visit the history page                            # features/step_definitions/path_steps.rb:10
    Then I should see "This is my edit summary"           # features/step_definitions/general_steps.rb:16

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/edit_with_blurbs.feature:6 # Scenario: Article Edit With Blurb

1 scenario (1 failed)
6 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 2 passed)
0m1.739s
```

```
...

Comment: Are you sure the "Edit" link is actually being correctly followed?  Also is whatever you have Capybara.default_max_wait_time (default_wait_time if using Capybara < 2.5.0)  long enough for the edit page to complete loading?

Comment: I edited the question to include the full test output.  It seems to show the Edit page being visited, but I am not sure how to verify that.

Comment: Is there unique text that would be on the edit page?  If so add a check for that before the "fill in" step.  One other thing to verify is that the field is actually visible on the page, this is often an issue when using JavaScript widgets that hide the real field and display a different field instead, or use overlayed elements to polyfill placeholder behavior, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the page is open then you can set the field by:

```
find(:id, "blurb").set("This is my edit summary")
```